# How to install tf1.15 as dependency for tensorpack?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

`tensorpack` requires a tensorflow version >= 1.5 and < 2, but it can not be installed with pip:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.5 (from versions: 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.5
```

Comment: Which Python version have you installed in your system? Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) reference to know about tested build configuration for installing right tensorflow version.

Comment: @TFer2 unfortunately I cannot tell anymore for sure, but I think it was 3.9. Meanwhilest I use PyTorch for my project. But thanks for the hint.